# Creating an AWS IAM policy that restricts running instances to certain security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I’m trying to write an IAM policy that only enables AWS users to launch an instance if the security group is one of two types. Because there is no security group Condition Key, I opted for using condition statements, such that an EC2 instance can't be started/run *unless* the security group is in either of the 2 categories. The way I refer to these approved security groups in the policy below is via their tags.

The issue I'm having is that when I have a security group that *does* equal the first condition, an instance can be launched. However, when I use the security group that does equal "UCSFInbound" (the second condition), an instance won't launch (even though it should).

I do have a separate policy which grants broader access to EC2 resources, however, from what I understand, AWS first registers "deny" actions before "allow" actions. And if this is the reason why I'm having a problem, then neither of the 2 cases (security groups) should work.

**IAM Policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:launch-template/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:placement-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-id": "NetworkResourcesStack"
                },
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "UCSFInbound"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This page is always useful for EC2 resource-level permissions: [Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API Actions - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html)

Comment: Note that, as written, your conditions are ANDed so both must be true for the Deny to take effect. If you want each on its own to cause denial then rewrite your policy to include two Deny statements for the same actions & resources, each having one condition.

Comment: If you can't achieve what you want in a proactive way with IAM policies, then you might consider a reactive approach using CloudTrail Logs and Lambda (where you respond to resources being created, you verify their state, and you stop or terminate them or alert someone if they're non-compliant).

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid using `Deny` policies unless it overrules other policies.

For example, you could control access to Amazon S3 like this:

1. `Allow` all staff access to all S3 buckets
2. `Deny` access to the HR bucket if you are not an HR staff member

This uses a generic policy to Allow most access, but then uses a Deny to cover a special-case.

Thus, you should put `arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/security-group-id` into the initial `Allow` policy that lets them use EC2.